# Asus i7 laptop does not detect Imation Apollo 1TB external HDD

Tags: windows, laptop, external-hard-drive

When I try to connect my Imation Apollo 1TB external HDD to my Asus i7 laptop, it doesn't work. I tried connecting it all the ports, but it doesn't work, however the ports are working properly (pendrives and external mouse work). Also that external HDD works with other laptops.

Comment: We could use more info such as, external drive file system (fat, ntfs, ext, etc..), Windows OS your trying to use, external drive manufacture. What shows up in Disk Management after connecting it?

Comment: @ChrisinNL windows 8 os, external drive file system fat, disk management doesn't show any detection, also if i plug mouse to another port with that hdd, mouse also doesn't work properly

Comment: @ChrisinNL does it power issue?

Comment: If your having issues on that port with other devices, it sounds like a faulty USB port. Contact the company for warranty. The 1tb drive should be formatted to NTFS, unless you chose FAT for a reason.

Comment: @ChrisinNL but without plug that external hdd, ports working properly

Comment: Strange. 3.5inch drives usually need a usb cable that supplies 5volt. 5.25inch drives sometimes require more power and need 2 usb plugs to get the drive powered on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17592/discussion-between-chrisinnl-and-user3099298).

Comment: Which version of Windows? Which Apollo drive? Some are not compatible with Windows 8, see http://www.imation.com/en-US/Consumer-Products/Consumer-Products/External-Hard-Disk-Drives/Apollo-Expert-D300-External-Hard-Drive/#Features-tab for example

Comment: This really sound like a power issue. @user3099298 Are you using the external power supply supplied with the Apollo external? Most laptops don't have the same power sinking capabilities as a desktop. Usually, windows should report it though...